# How do you stop GNOME Shell adding a second icon to the launcher even though the application is already favourited?

Tags: launcher, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate icons in GNOME Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73638/duplicate-icons-in-gnome-shell)

I've been playing around with GNOME Shell for a while and every thing is smooth. So much so that my biggest gripe is to do with the way the launcher handles some of my applications. For most part, when an application is added to the launcher, i.e. added to favourites, and loaded,  there will be only one instance of it shown in the launcher, with a white light shown under its icon.

But that doesn't seem to be the case for every application. A few, even though pinned to the launcher, show an additional icon once loaded. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if it is Java application you talking about - see http://locademiaz.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/turn-your-java-apps-gnome-shell-friendly/ for solution.

Basically this is issue related to how Gnome Shell (well, Docky too) matches windows using WM_CLASS property. Mentioned above solution is based on two things:
- binds arbitrary WM_CLASS string to the particular Java application,
- ensures that *.desktop file (think - launcher) has the same string as filename.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with the relevant instructions from that blog post? That way if the link breaks, at least we'll still have the instructions here. :)